# Flutter desktop Windows server support

Tags: windows, flutter, windows-server-2019

I am developing an app for windows, and I need it to work on Windows server 2019.
The flutter docs website mentions support for: Win 7 and above, and I'm not sure if that includes Windows server.
So, does flutter Desktop support Windows server 2019 and above?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run the application on windows server 2019, the application does not open, an error is logged:

```
Faulting application name: logbook.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x62fc7c7c
Faulting module name: logbook.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x62fc7c7c
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000005680
Faulting process id: 0x2590
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8b200df09b765
Faulting application path: C:\dev\logbook\logbook.exe
Faulting module path: C:\dev\logbook\logbook.exe
Report Id: fb88d338-89c8-4697-b637-5922dd9ad358
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Oh that's very unfortunate, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dr.Shower any solution currently found?

Comment: Unfortunately not, though my solution would be to just use a VM with any supported windows OS instead and run the app on it.